# Detection of function hooking in iOS

Tags: ios, security, hook, cydia-substrate

So far as I know, in iOS there are three techniques of function hooking:

1. preload library using DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES
2. imported symbol table redirection using [fishhook](https://github.com/facebook/fishhook)
3. patch the functions when they are already loaded - i.e. already in memory using [substrate MSHookFunction](http://www.cydiasubstrate.com/api/c/MSHookFunction/)

These expose security issues so I wanna be able to detect when such things happen. For point number 1, I can apply function pointer verification to detect. However for 2 and 3, I haven't had any idea. I am very thankful for ideas that can be done to address the issue.

Comment: Are you developing an app? If so, is it granted root permissions (jailbroken)? For #3 I'd recommend you to take a look at the [Cydia Substrate documentation](http://www.cydiasubstrate.com/id/264d6581-a762-4343-9605-729ef12ff0af/) and learn what methods it uses and how they work. Use a jailbroken device to discover exploits your app might be vulnerable to.

Comment: Yes, there is no reason not allowing my app to run on jailbroken devices.

Comment: For 3, all I can think of is to compare `.text` section of binary to `.text` section in memory. However, iOS binary is encrypted, so this approach is not feasible.

Comment: Have you ever solved this question? I'm trying to defeat xCon iOS tweak for jailbroken devices which seems to hook NSFileManager's methods. Any luck on defeating it?

Comment: I still have not found any acceptable solution for this. Please answer if you guys got any clue.

Comment: At first you can fishhook functions, that fishhook use for dynamic symbols rebinding.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue - trying to avoid any potential function hooking within my app.

My app was recently PEN tested and was found to have a vulnerability around function hooking. The security report referenced [Frida](https://www.frida.re) as one of the main culprits for executing such an act. I'm sure most of you peeps would be familiar with this tool.

[OWASP](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg/blob/master/Document/0x06j-Testing-Resiliency-Against-Reverse-Engineering.md) suggests a few remedial solutions for securing your app, but in this context, the section titled **Anti-Debugging Checks** would be the main focus.

As suggested by OWASP, I used ptrace with PT_DENY_ATTACH - denying a GDB/LLDB process to attach to the application.

*From OWASP:*

> In other words, using ptrace with PT_DENY_ATTACH ensures that no other debugger can attach to the calling process; if a debugger attempts to attach, the process will terminate

Here is the [solution](https://github.com/billwang1990/SwiftDenyPtrace) I used (for Swift). I also had help from this [Raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2664-ios-app-security-and-analysis-part-2-2) article (Objective-C). I can confirm that using the linked solution works - the app launches but the debugger cuts out, stopping all logs to the console. This could potentially deter hackers, but there will always be a way to get around this. As stated the Raywenderlich article linked:

> Don’t get too comfortable. Hackers often use Cycript, a JavaScript-styled program that can manipulate Objective-C apps at runtime. The scariest thing is that the previous logic to check for debugging activity fails when Cycript is attached. Remember, nothing is truly secure…

However, according to [Joseph Lord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858701/is-swift-resistant-against-hooking/29453212#29453212), writing apps using Swift can hopefully help you here. But then again, the reverse engineer always wins.

I hope this helps, in some way or form ...